# Why doesn't Entity Framework parameterize string comparisons, and how to fix this?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

Consider the following simple EF query:

```vb
dim id = db.Logins.Where(Function(x) x.FirstName <> "").Select(Function(x) x.Id).FirstOrDefault
```

In the usual EF way, this generates a sql query like

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Login] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT ((N'' = [Extent1].[FirstName]) AND ([Extent1].[FirstName] IS NOT NULL))
```

It's probably always done this, but suddenly this is causing a problem for me, because we have changed the `FirstName` column to use (Azure, SqlServer) database encryption.

It turns out that you cannot compare an encrypted column with a hardcoded variable; you have to use a parameter.

So this works:

```sql
select top 100 * from login where firstname is not null
```

and this works

```sql
DECLARE @param nvarchar(10) = ''
select top 100 * from login where firstname <> @param
```

But this:

```sql
select top 100 * from login where firstname <> ''
```

fails with the error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
> The data types nvarchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DBNAME') and varchar are incompatible in the not equal to operator.
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 1]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.

So in order to compare anything to an encrypted field, you need to use a parameter, not a hardcoded value like "", and so EF would need to generate that.

Is there a way to make EF do this?

Comment: It is a curious one... You could try using `string.Empty` or as a real hack this should work: `string empty = string.Empty;` then ` != empty`` That forces EF to recognize the comparison as a variable value and should trigger the parameter usage.  If that still doesn't work it is probably worth checking/raising with the EFCore team on Github, though it likely falls on the SQL Server provider for EF Core.

Comment: It doesn't even work with a string variable that isn't blank. EF6 uses the actual string, not the variable, even when using a vb/c# variable in the query.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, a fundamental aspect of EF is query parameterization. What provider are you using?

Comment: The latest Microsoft.Data.SqlClient provider.

Comment: But I agree, this doesn't make any sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a chance to test this with both EF Core and EF6 and it should work with a parameterization when you use a variable:

```
dim emptyName = ""

dim id = db.People.Where(Function(x) x.Name <> emptyName).Select(Function(x) x.PersonId).FirstOrDefault
```

Resulted in...

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [p].[PersonId]
FROM [People] AS [p]
WHERE ([p].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)) AND ([p].[Name] <> @__name_0)',N'@__name_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__name_0=N''
go
```

It did not work with `string.Empty` within the query, but did work with `string.Empty` in the variable declaration:

```
-- does not work
dim id = db.People.Where(Function(x) x.Name <> string.Empty).Select(Function(x) x.PersonId).FirstOrDefault

-- does work
dim emptyName = string.Empty
```

My VB.Net may not be correct, it's been ages since I've worked in VB vs. C#.

These examples worked against SQL Server without column encryption, so if they still don't work with encrypted columns or Azure SQL then that should warrant raising an issue with the EF Core maintainers.